# Error 0 after uninstalling Nicepage plugin

Tags: plugin, error

I uninstalled the Nicepage plugin in Joomla after I had problems with the menu on my website. I made a menu in Joomla with all of the articles, but it wouldn't show when I opened the website in the browser.

I wanted to uninstall Nicepage and reinstall it because I thought it would fix the problem, but immediately after that I got the following error on my Joomla account:

> Failed opening required '/customers/4/7/9/kabot.be/httpd.www/leercentrum/administrator/components/com_nicepage/library/loader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')

I can't do anything anymore in Joomla and I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: You probably need to ask on the Nicepage support page, wherever that is. If you made a menuitem then you could try going into phpmyadmin and setting that menuitem to unpublished. It would be in the <prefix>_menu table; find the relevant row and set the published field to 0 instead of 1.